# Why "System Update" app of "android 6.0" is draining battery

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life, system-apps

I am using Yu Yunicorn (5530) android phone. It has android marshmallow update. Recently I noticed when I put the phone on charging it takes long time to charge and never goes to 100%, also during the charging when I looked into the "Settings > battery" it shows "awake" green line throughout the period of charging.

Yesterday when I saw in the battery usage I found that "System Update" app is using 190% of battery and phone battery was draining very fast. When I forced stop the "System Update" it increased the battery life and also lets the charging up to 100%. When I put the phone on charging the "System Update" app starts and that slows down the charging. Also when I remove the phone from the charging it again starts "System Update" app. So every time I have to forced stop this app.
Now I would like your help to solve the problem, why my "System update" is using all of the battery and why it is running all the time, How can I solve the problem without factory reset? I already tried running phone in "safe mode" and "wipe cache partition" which did not help.

Thank you.